# sql query help? Sql newbie question

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1111

I keep getting this statement "Invalid use of group function"

for this query

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET users.lastmessage = MAX(messages.id) WHERE users.name ='tom'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

What I'm trying to do is take the lastmessage field in the users table and update it to be the largest id in the messages table where the name = tom

What did I do incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to execute a sub-query to get the maximum Id for the user 'tom' which is done as follows:

```
UPDATE users 
   SET users.lastmessage = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Messages WHERE messages.name = users.name) 
 WHERE users.Name = 'tom'
```

Edit: WHERE clause to only perform this for the correct user

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the MAX function outside of a GROUP BY statement.  You will need to do a SELECT statement inside your UPDATE query to get this value properly.  For example:

```
UPDATE users
SET users.lastmessage = (SELECT MAX(messages.id) AS m_id FROM messages WHERE messages.name = 'Tom')
WHERE users.name = 'Tom'
```

Notice, however, that this is a bit limited in that it is only updating Tom.  If you wanted to update every user, you could do so like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET users.lastmessage = (SELECT MAX(messages.id) AS m_id FROM messages WHERE messages.name = users.name)
```

This will update every user with the date of the last message they posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users, 
 (SELECT MAX(messages.id) as max_message_id FROM messages JOIN users ON (users.user_id = messages.user_id) WHERE users.name LIKE 'Tom') as mm 
 SET users.lastmessage = mm.max_message_id
 WHERE users.name = 'Tom'
```

I wouldn't say this is the *best* way to go about solving this, but because I know little about your table structure this seems to be doing what you want. Also keep in mind I haven't tested the above against so you'll need to change the tables and fields with your own proper ones.